# Parsing JSON data (from URL) in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve some data [from an URL](http://yahoojson.gobu.fr/symbol.php?symbol=MSFT) thanks to JSON. Here's my swift code:

```
// get symbol asked
let symbol = symbolField.text!

// define URL
let url = NSURL(string: "http://yahoojson.gobu.fr/symbol.php?symbol=\(symbol)")!

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let urlContent = data {
        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

            print(jsonResult)
        } catch {
            print("Error JSON")
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Everything seems to work fine, but the `"do-try-catch"` always prints `"Error JSON"`. My code seems unable to convert my URL content into actual JSON. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL returns html/javascript not pure json.

Paste the URL into your browser and look at the source code.

A side note: replace

```
print("Error JSON")
```

with

```
print(error)
```

to get more specific error information